# Receive JSON in PHP and save input as TXT file

Tags: php, json, rest

I am new to PHP and I would like to accomplish the following.

Receive a JSON request and store the results in a txt file. The JSON request I send :

```
{"first_name":"William"}
```

The PHP code i used to receive the JSON :

```
        <?php

$request = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = json_decode($request);

$firstName = $input;

$text = print_r($firstName,true);
file_put_contents('output.txt', var_export($text, TRUE));
```

The text file is created, but there is no content in the text file.

Comment: You aren't doing any error checking at all. My guess is that either `$request` is empty or `json_decode()` returns null.

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: As i already mentioned i am complete new to PHP. What is the best way for error checking in PHP ?

Comment: Check your error logs. Do you have permissions to write to the file?

Comment: The output txt file is created so permissions are ok

Comment: Is this a GET or POST request? What is the contents of `$text`?

Comment: try this json_decode($request,true);

Comment: It is a POST request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works

```
$request = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = json_decode($request,true);

$firstName = $input['first_name];

$text = print_r($firstName,true);
file_put_contents('output.txt', var_export($text, TRUE));
```

Answer (score 0):

use this codes

```
if(isset($_POST['input']){
 $input$_POST['input']; 

file_put_contents('output.txt', var_export($input, TRUE));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

Replace

```
$text = print_r($firstName,true);
```

with

```
$text = $input->{'first_name'};
```

Or use this

```
$firstName =$input->{'first_name'};

$text = print_r($firstName,true);
```

Comment: When i use this, i receive the following error : <b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\API\signup2.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />    Line 6 is the line : $firstName =$input->{'first_name'};

Comment: Try after change name of input  to input.json

Comment: Sorry i don't understand what you mean with, try after change name

Comment: $request = file_get_contents('php://input'); this should be $request = file_get_contents('input.json');

Comment: The file name in which this {"first_name":"William"} is written , should be  input.json .   This file should be "json" type.